# Is kernel samepage merging safe?

Tags: settings, performance

In the performance section of android 4.4.4 Oneplus one i saw kernel samepage merging . i want to know is it safe ? as when i entered the performance section it gave warning that these setting are experimental .

Comment: No automatic same page merging though. The version in the android kernel requires processes to tell the kernel about which pages can be merge (not useful as none done this). If you want all processes being scanned for pages that can be merged, please try http://web.archive.org/web/20171215154856/http://kerneldedup.org/projects/uksm/introduction/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used samepage merging a long time ago until I just recently updated my device and back then it worked perfectly. There were no problems regarding speed, errors (no graphical artifacts, inaccuracies, bricks etc.) or safety.

Samepage merging merges two identical portions of data in RAM to the same memory pointer which then saves the extra amount of memory needed to store additional images, sprites, binary files etc. for instance.  It's correct that these features are being tested before they get released/activated in the default source code.

From the [KVM site](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/KSM) we read about KSM (kernel samepage merging):

> KSM is a memory-saving de-duplication feature, that merges anonymous (private) pages (not pagecache ones). Although it started this way, KSM is currently not suitable only for Virtual Machine use, but rather, it can be useful to any application which generates many instances of the same data